# Golang end function after any go routine finishes

Tags: go

I have a main function that looks like so:

```
func main() {
    go SyncRealTime()
    go SyncStale()
}
```

Both of these functions are supposed to continue indefinitely. I'd like for `main` to:

- Not terminate as long as both Goroutines are running.
- Terminate if either one of the Goroutines terminates (i.e. errors)

What is the idiomatic way of doing that in Go?

Comment: From the [go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

`Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the
function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.`

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of doing it:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        SyncRealTime()
        c <- "SyncRealTime"
    }()

    go func() {
        SyncStale()
        c <- "SyncStale"
    }()

    firstDone := <-c
    fmt.Println(firstDone + " exited")
    // done
}
```